# partial view not opening as jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I need to open a partial view as dialog box on click of a button, basically add/ Edit scenario. My problem is that mu partial view does open but not as a dialog but at the bottom of the page.

Please see my code below:
I have an empty div on the page:

On the click of the button I call the below code:

function addSelectionActivate() {
        var selectionID = 0;

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "AddEditSelection",
        type: "POST",
        data: "&selectionID=" + selectionID,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#addEditSelectionDialog").html(data);
            $("#addEditSelectionDialog").dialog('open');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status);
        }
    });
}
```

My controller has a method "AddEditSelection" which returns the result. But the partial view opens at the end of the page rather than as a dialog. Please help what I might b edoing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the partial in a seperate div contained in the dialog div.

eg:

```
<div id="DialogDiv">
    <div id="AnotherDiv">

    </div>
</div>
```

and register "DialogDiv" as dialog and load ur partial in the "AnotherDiv"

Comment: Sorry I cun't understand by what you mean by register "DialogDiv" as dialog

Comment: ok, it is similar to this

' $("#ajax-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function () { }     });'

this way you register a div as a dialog